# Python Regex Capture Between Specific Characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm struggling with some regex for a few parts of these strings below. This for use in a str.extract() and I need to capture:

- jump or crawl, this will follow two spaces
- valueA or valueB, this will follow the $
- amount between @ and \n, sometimes, but not always, this includes up to two decimals

```
⬆️  jump $valueA @ 5084\n\n#blah
⬆️  jump $valueB @ 628.15\n\n#blah
⬇️  crawl $valueB @ 626.8\n\n#blah
⬇️  crawl $valueB @ 4070\n\n#blah
⬆️  jump $valueA @ 6175.5\n\n#blah
```

Comment: Do you want to capture `valueA` on assembly lines beginning with `crawl`, or only those lines beginning with `jump` ?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/PYc5F4/1) help?

Comment: I suppose `ValueA` or `ValueB` are not literally what you are after. Give [this](https://regex101.com/r/PYc5F4/3) a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern `(jump|crawl)\s+\$(value[AB])\s@\s(\d*\.?\d*)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value":["⬆️  jump $valueA @ 5084\n\n#blah",
                            "⬆️  jump $valueB @ 628.15\n\n#blah",
                            "⬇️  crawl $valueB @ 626.8\n\n#blah",
                            "⬇️  crawl $valueB @ 4070\n\n#blah",
                            "⬆️  jump $valueA @ 6175.5\n\n#blah"]})

print (df["value"].str.extract("(jump|crawl)\s+\$(value[AB])\s@\s(\d*\.?\d*)"))

       0       1       2
0   jump  valueA    5084
1   jump  valueB  628.15
2  crawl  valueB   626.8
3  crawl  valueB    4070
4   jump  valueA  6175.5
```